# Answer deleted 5 days ago appearing in new beta review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Review System showing deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143531/new-review-system-showing-deleted-answer)

When reviewing low quality posts in the new beta review queue, I'm frequently coming across deleted posts, some of which are more than several days old. Nothing on the review page indicates that it was deleted, but if you click on the permalink to the answer it is not there.

I would understand if there was some small caching differences, but I've just seen an obviously commercial spam post in the queue that was deleted 5 days ago. I've seen this 4 or 5 times today out of the last 100 or so reviews that I have done.

For example, this happens for https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/208621.

Note that if I refresh the page, or open it via that URL, I get the notice that *This item is no longer available*, but it shows up as a real post when it is presented for the first time.

Is it possible to flush the deleted posts, or at least put a notice on the question that it has been deleted? When I see obvious spam posts, I have to navigate away from reviewing to go to the original page (because there's no option to flag for spam from inside the review queue), only to find that it does not exist.

I have seen this question marked completed for the old review queue, though I cannot find any duplicate of this referring to the new beta review tasks.

Comment: "deleted Aug 4 at 20:31" on that spam post..

Comment: Thanks. Note that I received this in the review queue today (Aug 9).

Comment: I like how it displays "other answers -1" at the side.

Comment: @animuson hehe... yeah; I figure `TOTAL_VIEWABLE_ANSWERS - 1` is how that's arrived at ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is "by-design": I "incorrectly" processed a deleted response and was "admonished" for it.

In fact I didn't agree with that admonishment. (FYI, here is the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/211284), but the answer has now been deleted from the review too. It said "efax is a big provider but it's really painful for the end-user" and suggested another provider with two links.)

Comment: [Admonishment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/admonishment). Hmmm, that doesn't help ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Based on that definition it is the word I meant.

Comment: Seeing as the duplicate was marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign], it looks like I was right :-)