# New review system showing deleted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I was reviewing some stuff today, and I came across a rather ridiculous answer (see screenshot). I wanted to see the question and other answers, so I clicked on the link, and found that the answer I was reviewing was in fact deleted. Could someone take a look at it?

[Review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/219644)

[Question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623305/how-to-fix-a-div-or-a-panel-after-some-scroll-in-gwt)

> [image]

Comment: For the record, I'd have up-voted that answer! Just too bad they weren't offering any Discount Gucci Handbags...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the other side of [this earlier question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality).

We throw some real garbage into the queue as "audit" tasks to catch misuse* of the feature, just handle them normally.

<sub>*Typically clicking "looks good" or "delete" without reading the post.</sub>

Comment: Neat idea. Looks like you're using spam flag deleted content as an audit?

Comment: @Ben That's roughly the algorithm right now.  It will probably get more subtle with time.

Comment: So you'll show answers full of unicorns and permaban the account of anyone that clicks delete?

Comment: *"just handle them normally."* Wouldn't the appropriate action here be to go to the post and flag it (which we cannot do because it's already gone)? There's no option under 'recommend deletion' for commercial spam. I don't oppose the use of 'trick questions', but it's kind of mean to send us searching for the spam flag when the post no longer exists.

Comment: Can these be made less obvious? Example: http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/567151

Comment: This is completely contrary to the rest of the site.  You have an automatic question and answer ban, which counts self deleted posts on it with the justification that of wasted users time.  Guess what? Putting that bogus stuff in the review queue is wasting the users time.  So why is it OK for the system to waste a users time but not another user?  There has got to be a better way to check for tool misuse than this.