# Low quality review queue showing already deleted items

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Review System showing deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143531/new-review-system-showing-deleted-answer)

This doesn't seem to be reported yet.. unless it is buried somewhere.

The Low Quality review queue is showing answers that have already been deleted.

Here is the [review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/807036), and here is the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12868170/109702).

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Further info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143380/159165