# Force / Encourage Answers with explanation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Lately i have seen many answers to "trivial" questions being just a block of code, which is, I must admit, most of the times very self-explanatory and obvious, but only to people with a bit  more knowledge than the newly created 10 rep whatever-beginner.

please compare [revision one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18696387/revisions) and revision two. it is not much of a problem to write three lines of explanation, instead of providing a solution, and having OP return for a simple variation of the problem.

Thus I would like to discuss the introduction of a feature:

Dialog-Box with "please consider adding further explanation to you answer", when a submitted answer consists only of a code-block

Comment: Related: [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers while blocking code-only questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Comment: Should this mechanism count comments in code as explanation enough?

Comment: @Mołot pff, who writes those?

Comment: @Bart for example [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/85332/16495) you can see important explanation as a comment on `get_next_steps` function.

Comment: Downvote and add a comment when you find those.

Comment: Is this "force", isn't it more "suggest"

Comment: @Mołot - I've seen questions where the actual question was in a code comment. And it is often glossed over - people don't read the code comments - they look for the question in the body of the question.

Comment: @Oded I'm not arguing. I just wanted this aspect covered. And I know I can't tell what people read, I read the comments in the code I'm suggested to use, but hey, I also read leaflets from my allergy drugs for example.

Comment: @Mołot [like that](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/159965/31260)? Have to admit, of few hundreds answers I posted at SO and Programmers, only about a handful allowed to keep _substantial_ message within code comments. As a rule, I have to put important stuff outside the code to make an answer readable (answer readability is important because it helps to get upvotes)