# Answering with just code

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, code, answer-quality

Is it bad practice to answer with just code and no explanation?  I had someone complain about this once but everyone seems to do it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/172661, which discusses the matter in great detail.

Comment: Searched for one of them, couldn't find it.

Comment: int main() { printf("yes\n"); return 0; }

Comment: code tags please ;)

Comment: You didn't search very hard. :-) I found and linked it with zero keystrokes and a few mouseclicks - see the second-to-last topic in the **Related** list to the right, click it, and then click the link to the duplicate that resulted in it being closed as a duplicate.