# Should beginner questions be offered optimized code?

Tags: discussion, answers, optimization

So, regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562959/swing-app-only-shows-one-record-in-jtextarea/20562977#20562977).  I answered that to append to a `JTextArea`, you simply don't use the `setText()` method, you use `append()`.  As the OP was obviously not a skilled programmer, I thought a simple answer would do.  Why complicate things with discussion of what seems to me to be premature optimization?

The other answer thought differently (not mentioning the [lack of description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208999/answering-with-just-code) :P).  Should I be offering the most optimal solution even a slight cost to clarity?

Comment: An explanation as you gave is better than a code only answer, especially for new users.

Comment: Why not do both? Offer the simple solution with explanation and a more optimized way.

Comment: Suppose yea. I wrote my simple answer though and to extend it to include the other answer-er would feel fraudulent :P

Comment: @RossDrew If people comment on your answer they are suggesting you take that information and add it to your answer. All information in comments is fair game (although it's always nice to thank the people who provide it)

Comment: Yeah, if only I could properly thank people though :P http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209011/rep-sharing-would-be-nice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually for questions with an easy, perfectly fine (read not open to SQL attacks etc) not great answer and an advanced solution thats beyond the abilities of the OP I usually answer with a main answer section and an "Ideas for improvement" section. This gives the best of both worlds.

This is useful both for the OP (as they can stretch themselves if they choose) and for future visitors who may be able to implement the advanced solution

Answer (score 6):

Regarding "Ideas for improvement", if there's just a few couple of things and you have time/energy to add them then feel free to do so. Otherwise, there is a whole other StackExchange site dedicated for that:

[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

If you feel that the user could use some more in-depth explanations about how to write cleaner / more optimized code, feel free to redirect them to Code Review. However, be sure that you read [Code Review's about page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/about) before asking them to go there. In summary, Code Review is for:

- **Working** code (once they got their problem fixed on StackOverflow, they can go to Code Review to make their code even better), or code that is believed to be working.
- Optimizing speed of code
- Improving the cleaniness of the code

Code Review is **not** for:

- Fixing problems with existing code
- Understanding what the code does (Teachers are better at this)
- Helping users debug errors or incorrect results
- Improving code written by someone other than the asker
- Questions of low quality

Answer (score 1):

Better solutions can be harder to understand and still be clear. As I see it the main issue isn't for the OP to understand your solution asap, but all those who read the post.

If you can, give both solutions, if you insist of choosing one, I would go with the optimal one.